# Parse json object to kotlin data class list like an hasmap

Tags: android, json, kotlin, parsing, hashmap

i have one difficult to parse one jsonObject to data class object, I need that one list of this object:

```
data class DataClassExample(val mandatory: Boolean,
val name: String,
val regex: String?,
val regex_check: Boolean)
```

and I have this json object where each list object I need transform in one single list of the data class object:

```
{
"defaultParameters": [
{
  "name": "business",
  "mandatory": true,
  "type": "String",
  "regex": "",
  "regex_check": true
},
{
  "name": "environment",
  "mandatory": true,
  "type": "String",
  "regex": "",
  "regex_check": true
}
],
"userParameters": [
{
  "name": "person_id",
  "mandatory": true,
  "type": "String",
  "regex": "",
  "regex_check": true
} ]
```

I will filter by objectName, for example "defaultParameters", and convert the list in the data class, my expected result is:

```
listOf(DataClassExample(name = "", mandatory = true, type = "String", regex = "", ...), DataClassExample(...))
```

I tryed get this value using this code:

```
val response = allowList.filterKeys {
        it == "defaultParameters"
    } as MutableMap<String, String>
```

but I dont now how transform this code in data class list.
Tks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to pull in a Serialization library, for example [Kotlin Serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)

It's unclear if you're trying to only serialize/deserialize a subset of the json, if so you'll need to parse it first.

Here's an example deserializing the entire `data`.

We'll use the Serializable annotations.

Let's create a `data class` to hold both default and user params:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class AllParameters(
    val defaultParameters: List<Parameters>,
    val userParameters: List<Parameters>
)

@Serializable
data class Parameters(
    val mandatory: Boolean,
    val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val regex: String?,
    @SerialName("regex_check")
    val regexCheck: Boolean
)
```

And deserialzing to object:

```kotlin
val obj = Json.decodeFromString<AllParameters>(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

I can recommend a 3rd party library call [Klaxon](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon)

Import it with adding this to your Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:5.5'
    ...
}
```

If your list is:

```
val data = """[
            {
              "name": "business",
              "mandatory": true,
              "type": "String",
              "regex": "",
              "regex_check": true
            },
            {
              "name": "environment",
              "mandatory": true,
              "type": "String",
              "regex": "",
              "regex_check": true
            }
         ]"""
```

The Parsing line would be:

```
Klaxon().parseArray<DataClassExample>(data)
```